# How to use SQL Server Profiler with an Azure SQL Server with AAD integrated security where AAD user is different from logged in desktop account?

Tags: sql-server, azure, sql-server-profiler

Scenario:

1. User logged in to desktop using domain account
2. User has an Azure account in AAD which is different from the domain account
3. Azure SQL database with AAD authentication configured for the Azure account

How can user profile the SQL queries sent to the Azure SQL database using SQL Server Profiler?

Comment: You should consider SQL Profiler to be a deprecated tool and start using Extended Events instead. That being said Microsoft does provide an [SQL Profiler-like extension for Azure Data Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/sql-server-profiler-extension) that itself consumes Extended Events.

Comment: Sounds like an answer to me. Why not arrange your comment as an answer so I could credit you?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Thanks for @AlwaysLearning's help:

"You should consider SQL Profiler to be a deprecated tool and start using Extended Events instead. That being said Microsoft does provide an [SQL Profiler-like extension for Azure Data Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/extensions/sql-server-profiler-extension?view=sql-server-ver15) that itself consumes Extended Events"

We're glad that that could be an answer for you.

I just help him post it and this can be beneficial to other community members. Thank @AlwaysLearning again!